# How could I Pass props from grandparent Component to grandson Component

Tags: reactjs, jsx, antd

I have struggled with the pass props issue for few days but haven't figure out how to achieve this.

In my Project, I have a rechart page `index.js` and the inherit relationship looks like: `index.js => RechartsComponent => LineChartComponent` But I can't prop the list from index.js to its grandchild LineChartComponent to replace the data source of SimpleLineChart. I have tried different ways but nothing works. Any advice will be appreciated.

**index.js**

```
  render() {
    const { rechartdata } = this.props
    const { list } = rechartdata
   
    return (
      <Page inner>
        <RadioGroup
          options={chartList}
          defaultValue="lineChart"
          onChange={this.handleRadioGroupChange}
        />
        <div className={styles.chart}>
          <ReChartsComponent type={this.state.type} list={list} />
        </div>
      </Page>
    )
  }
```

**RechartsComponent.js**

```
const ReChartsComponent = ({ type,list}) => {
  if (type === 'areaChart') return <AreaChartComponent />
  if (type === 'barChart') return <BarChartComponent />
  return <LineChartComponent list={list}/>
 
}
```

**LineChartComponent.js**

```
const SimpleLineChart = ({list}) => (
  <Container>
    <LineChart
    //  data={data}
    data={list}
      margin={{
        top: 5,
        right: 30,
        left: 20,
        bottom: 5,
      }}
    >
      <XAxis dataKey="name" />
      <YAxis />
      <CartesianGrid strokeDasharray="3 3" />
      <Tooltip />
      <Legend />
      <Line
        type="monotone"
        dataKey="id"
        stroke="#8884d8"
        activeDot={{
          r: 8,
        }}
      />
     
    </LineChart>
  </Container>
)

const LineChartPage = () => (
  <div className="content-inner">
    <Button
      type="primary"
      style={{
        position: 'absolute',
        right: 0,
        top: -48,
      }}
    >
      <a
        href="http://recharts.org/#/en-US/examples/TinyBarChart"
        target="blank"
      >
        Show More
      </a>
    </Button>
    <Row gutter={32}>
      <Col {...colProps}>
        <Card title="Simple Chart">
          <SimpleLineChart />
        </Card>
      </Col>
      <Col {...colProps}>
        <Card title="DashedLineChart">
          <DashedLineChart />
        </Card>
      </Col>
      <Col {...colProps}>
        <Card title="CustomizedDotLineChart">
          <CustomizedDotLineChart />
        </Card>
      </Col>
      <Col {...colProps}>
        <Card title="VerticalLineChart">
          <VerticalLineChart />
        </Card>
      </Col>
    </Row>
  </div>
)

export default LineChartPage
```

Comment: Why the `Card` component is called on the first line of the `RechartsComponent` component?

Comment: @wowandy sorry its a typo. I forgot to remove the ANTD card. But it doesn't fix the problem

Comment: you forgot to pass `list` props from `LineChartPage` to `SimpleLineChart`. That's it

Comment: @glinda93 Thanks so much for your help. I just tried that but it looks like the content didn't even proped to LineChartPage. I added a Card in LineChartPage to output list but it just return blank.

Comment: @JokiesDing If you're not going to use context api, just console log everywhere you pass `list` props. I believe it's just a simple overlook.

Answer (score 0):

Reason is simply what you're exporting for `LineChartComponent.js` is `export default LineChartPage`

Hence when you define `LineChartPage`, you need to have `prop` for that

```js
const LineChartPage = ({list}) => (
...
)
```

Something good to have but not mandatory is that having the same file name as component will avoid careless mistake like what you've made, such as below

LineChartComponent.js

```js
const LineChartComponent = ({list})=> (
...
)

export default LineChartComponent;
```

Keep the name of your component and the file name consistent

Comment: Its so appreciated for your comment! I just tried the solution but it looks like list did not even get proped to LineChartPage = ({list}). I tried to add a card to output the content of list in LineChartPage and it just return blank.

Comment: in that case I would suggest you to comment out all the code and trace from there, im certain it's due to the import and exporting that you've confused yourself along the way @JokiesDing

Answer (score -1):

First off, in your example, the `SimpleLineChart` isn't receiving a list from `LineChartPage`. You would need to add a list prop to `LineChartPage` and pass that into `SimpleLineChart`

That said, when I need to pass props past more than one level of depth, I generally switch to the Context API.

1. I would create a context provider for the state you want to pass down:

```js
import { createContext, FC, useReducer } from "react";

// ...

const InitialState : GrandparentStateI = {
    // As you wish...
}

export const GrandparentContext = createContext(InitialState);

// ...

grandparentContextReducer = (state : GrandparentStateI, action : {
    type : string,
    payload : any
})=>{

    switch(action.type){
       // ...
    }

}

export const GrandparentContextProvider : FC<{}> = ({children})=>{
   

   const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(grandparentContextReducer, InitialState);

   return (

        <GrandparentContext.Provider value={state}>{children}</GrandparentContext.Provider>

    )

}
```

2. Define a hook which you will use to access the context:

```js
export const useGrandparentContext = () : GrandparentContextProps =>{

    const context = useContext(GrandparentContext);

    if(!context._inProvider){ // I usually have an _inProvider member
        throw new Error("useGrandparentContext must be called within a GrandparentProvider.");
    }

    return {
        ...context,
    };

}
```

3. Wrap the Grandparent's children in the provider;

```js
const Grandparent : FC<{...}> = ({children})=>{

   return (
      <div>
         // ...
         <GrandparentContextProvider>{children}</GrandparentContextProvider>
     </div>

   )

}
```

4. Call the hook from the grandchildren at whatever depth:

```js
const Grandchild : FC<{...}> = ()=>{

    const {
        ...
    } = useGrandparentContext();

    return (

        // ...

    )

}
```

The Context API generally makes refactoring or adding layers of depth much easier than other patterns.